# Hiding members in public interface and ODR

Tags: c++, c++11, static-libraries, one-definition-rule

**I have multiple classes in a library that have internals that I wish to hide from client code.** From the client's perspective, each class is queried from a library class and is only used as an opaque pointer. An example is as follows:

```
struct SomeSystem;
void doSomethingToSomeSystem(SomeSystem* system, Parameters params);
void doSomethingElseToSomeSystem(SomeSystem* system, Parameters params);
```

**On the implementation side, SomeSystem has multiple members which are not visible to the caller.** This is all fine but I don't really like the clunky usage syntax:

```
SomeSystem* system = lib->getSomeSystem();
doSomethingToSomeSystem(system, params);
doSomethingElseToSomeSystem(system, params);
```

Another approach is this:

```
struct SomeSystem;
namespace somesystem {
    void doSomething(SomeSystem* system, Parameters params);
    void doSomethingElse(SomeSystem* system, Parameters params);
}
```

With the usage code:

```
SomeSystem* system = lib->getSomeSystem();
somesystem::doSomething(system, params);
somesystem::doSomethingElse(system, params);
```

I could also use global methods called `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` and depend on function overloading if another type also defines `doSomething`. However, in this case, it is hard to find all "members" of SomeSystem in an IDE.

**I am tempted to actually use member functions:**

```
struct SomeSystem {
    void doSomething(Parameters params);
    void doSomethingElse(Parameters params);
};
```

With the usage code:

```
SomeSystem* system = lib->getSomeSystem();
system->doSomething(params);
system->doSomethingElse(params);
```

**The last snippet looks good to me but SomeSystem is no longer an opaque pointer - it actually defines members.** I'm a bit wary of this. One potential problem is the one definition rule. However, the "public" definition and "private" definition of the class will only be visible to different translation units. Is there any other badness hidden here? If the client code tries to instantiate SomeSystem on the stack or using new it would obviously crash the program. But I'm willing to accept that. Perhaps I can get around this by providing a private constructor in the public interface.

Another approach is of course to define an abstract class with pure virtual methods. **However, I would like to avoid the overhead of this in case it is not absolutely necessary.**

**EDIT:**

To be clear I am wondering if it is legal to have a public header that the client includes containing a different definition of the class (with some members missing) than what the implementation uses, as the client never instantiates the class.

Public header:

```
struct SomeSystem {
    void doSomething(Parameters params);
    void doSomethingElse(Parameters params);
};
```

Private header:

```
struct SomeSystem {
    Member member;
    void doSomething(Parameters params);
    void doSomethingElse(Parameters params);
};
```

Private source (includes private header):

```
void SomeSystem::doSomething(Parameters params) {
    ...
}
void SomeSystem::doSomethingElse(Parameters params) {
    ...
}
```

This works when I test it but I am unsure if it violates the standard somehow. The two headers are never included in the same translation unit.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Opaque Pointer/Pimpl Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)?

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with it and I'd rather avoid it. It introduces extra memory allocation and complicates implementation.

Comment: Note that I am specifically after syntactic sugar without making my solution worse performance or complexity wise.

Comment: You could, instead of using an interface superclass/parent, have the class own the interface. That way, the interface remains static, and you can just create a class to own the interface and use it when required.

Comment: That would require virtual functions, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You're basically looking for polymorphic capabilities from a single interface. You're bound to have to use polymorphism unless you write the interface in such a way that you do the system-type-checking within your static interface, right?

Comment: I believe it's either standardize the capabilities of each system so that they all basically do the same thing, poll for specific capabilities by parametrizing the capability you want, or use polymorphism.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure you don't want to have to do something like check a specific ENUM or a string parameter to get the polymorphism without vtables.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. I'm not looking for polymorphism. There's no inheritance involved. I'm just looking to hide implementation details of a class without inheritance. Thus I want to omit some members in a public header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74207/discussion-between-cinch-and-rasmus).

Answer (score 0):

The PIMPL idiom is probably ideal in this situation, but it is an extra indirection on every access so there is that.

An alternative if you're just after some syntactic sugar might be to take advantage of ADL - it'll at least keep the system name out of the function name:

```
// publicly shared header file
namespace one_system
{
  struct system;
  typedef system* system_handle;
  void do_something(system_handle );
};

// private implementation
namespace one_system
{
  struct system {};
  void do_something( system_handle ) { cout << "one"; }
};


int main() {
  auto handle = /* SOMETHING TO GET THIS SYSTEM */;
  do_something(handle); //do_something found by ADL
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

I still think PIMPL is ideal. You also don't necessarily need to have an allocation nor any additional overhead compared to what you have already.

In the case where you have a system* and a function declaration (as per your examples), the compiler already has to do an indirection. You'll need a jump to that function (as it is defined in another translation unit) and indirections to access the system within the function (since it is taken as a pointer).

All you really need to do is define an interface for the class like so:

```
// put this in a namespace or name it according to the system
class interface
{
    system_handle m_system;

    public:
    interface( system_handle s ) : m_system( s ) {}
    interface() = delete;

    void do_something();
};
```

Now in another translation unit, do_something() is defined to perform it's operation on the system. The lib->GetSystem() could return an instance of the interface. The interface can be fully declared in the header file since it only consists of the public functions. The system is still entirely private (in that the user of the lib won't have the header file declaring it's contents).

Furthermore the interface can be trivially copied around by the user. It doesn't care where it's pointer comes from so the library could pass in the address of a static if it wants.

The one downside I can see to this would be that member variables would need to have accessors (and there are many who would argue that every member variable should be private and have public or protected accessors anyway).

Another would be that the *this for interface would be passed into do_something and is probably not needed. This could be solved by having do_something defined in the header file too:

```
void do_something() { do_something_to_system( m_system ); }
```

Now the compiler should be able to optimize even the *this out since do_something can be inlined and the compiler could easily just insert code to load m_system into a register and call do_something_to_system (which would be similar to what you've mentioned in your examples).

Comment: I disagree. PIMPL is not ideal since it, like you say, introduces an extra indirection. Worse, it introduces an extra memory allocation and puts more burden on the implementation. Your example with one_system won't work unless you do `using namespace do_something`. Is is also exactly what I discussed in my question. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @rasmus What part of it won't work? You don't need to do using namespace do_something for the compiler to find the function - you just need to have the handle or system be declared in the same namespace as the function.

Comment: Ok my bad, I missed that system was defined inside the namespace. I still think it is a problem that an IDE won't list the members unless you type one_system:: though.

Comment: So your answer is basically a variation of the alternatives above. Thanks for adding another suggestion to the list. However, I still think the last version is nicest. What I would like to know is if that version is broken, and if it is, the reason for it. It is very much working on multiple compilers and platforms.

Comment: @rasmus the last version you mention has nothing wrong with it but what I assume your query is: how to keep an expected syntax with low performance overhead but have the system's innards kept private from the user of the library. I have amended my answer with one additional option for consideration.

Comment: No, actually, the last version shows the public interface and usage. Potential problems involve ODR because multiple definitions of the same class exists in the program. This is what the question is about. Sorry if that was unclear.